# Iterate a list and create a single variable(string)

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have a list which has multiple environments. I want to iterate it and create a single variable by using the iterated value.

For example:

```
{{ environment }} = [local, dev, prod]
```

using the loop I should be able to create a single variable

```
{{ new_varible}} =>
This is local environment,This is dev environment,This is prod environment
```

I am very new to Ansible. I am unable to find one solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify each element with `map` and `join` into string:

```
set_fact:
  new_var: "{{ environment | map('regex_replace', '(.*)','This is \\1 environment') | list | join(', ') }}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try this one.